# How can I see a list of available imports for python?

Tags: python, import, raspberry-pi

### **Question:**

**From terminal,  What command do I run to browse the list of possible imports I have available for python?**

---

I just bought a raspberry pi b+ with Raspberrian (a build on debian).

I'm trying to learn how to use it and everyone defaults to python.

I've never worked with a microcontroller or python as a general language.

in one of my first examples I'll be making a LED turn on.

What i've first noticed is the `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO` on the top line of the example

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

led = 11

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(led,GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(led,GPIO.HIGH)
```

I've had to work in other languages with similar import concepts but I'm much more curious of how would I have known that I needed to import that GPIO library?  Is there a well documented list of libraries I should know for raspberry pi?

I feel like this resource will help me understand what's even possible with this PI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Python shell, this will solve your problem:

```
help('modules')
```

[image]

For your second question check [**this**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/) link. Or just a quick search in google, that's all.

> Also you can check if a module is succesfully installed or not, just *import modulename* in Python shell, if nothing happens, then you installed it succesfuly. If it gives an error like *ImportError: No module named 'modulename'* then you did something wrong when you installed that module.

Comment: how do these packages get installed?  rather how would I install a new one? where would i find more of them them?

Comment: They are coming with Python already, if you see some 3rd party modules in this picture that means I installed them manually before.